# object passing in loop -- python

Tags: python, object, for-loop, ironpython, python-2.6

I am passing a big object in a `for` loop to a function and in that function accessing attributes of the object in another loop since this seemed the best way. However, I then got a slowdown by a factor of almost 1000 and hence I changed the passing of an object to passing of required attributes and now it works fine.

The object passed is a binary object imported by `clr` and not a python object.

But when I did a standalone test like below I get totally opposite results.

Here is my test:

```
class test_Obj():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 34
        self.y = 34
        self.z = 34

class test_Obj2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x2 = test_Obj()
        self.y2 = test_Obj()
        self.z2 = test_Obj()

def test1(test_Obj2):
    res = list()
    for i in range(100000):
        res.append(test_Obj2.z2.z)
    return res

def test2(z):
    res = list()
    for i in range(100000):
        res.append(z)
    return res

def test3():
    res = list()
    start_time = time()
    for i in range(1000):
        res.append(test1(test_Obj2()))
    end_time = time()
    print end_time - start_time
    start_time = time()
    for i in range(1000):
        res.append(test2(test_Obj2().z2.z))
    end_time = time()
    print end_time - start_time
```

and the output that I got is as below

```
>>> import temp as t
>>> t.test3()
94.2169342041
423.085632324
```

Can anyone please help me understand this behaviour?

Comment: You need to *repeatedly* test something to eliminate the influence of other processes on your PC, including swapping and disk buffer flushes. One run of each test is not enough to determine a clear difference. Use the `timeit` module and have it run your tests in a loop.

Comment: I am using API and the python interpreter gives me following output when I try to use `timeit`                           
`RuntimeWarning: IronPython has no support for disabling the GC`

Comment: That's just a warning; disabling the GC would help avoid another factor that can influence timings, but you can still test your timings with GC enabled.

Comment: It took its time but didnt produce any timings 
anyways I will test same thing on other machine

Answer (score 0):

Your first test creates a list with 1000 elements each of which is a list of 100,000 integers. That's 100,000,000 list elements.

The second test creates a further 1000 lists of 100,000 integers which it stores on the end of the first 1000 lists.

This could be slower because you have run out of real memory and started paging to disc, or because garbage collection kicked in and had to check the previous 100,000,000 elements to mark them as still accessible, or perhaps just because something else was running on your system at the time.

Use `timeit` as Martijn suggested, and be sure to clean up after the first test (or better run two separate scripts). My guess would be that when all else is equal passing in the object will be ever so slightly slower (because you have 200,000,000 attribute lookups rather than 2000 in test2).